# How do I expand both the variable and the wildcard in a bash string?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to store in the TEMP variable the result of the following command:

```
TEMP="$(ls $dest_dir.*)"
```

The issue here is that only the variable is expanded, not the * wildcard. What I get from the expansion is:

```
dir_01.*
```

where dir_01 is the value in dest_dir. And that makes the *ls* command to fail.

How can I have the wildcard expanded as well?

Comment: You must not have a directory named `dir_01.*`. If you did the glob would expand. When there's no match it's left unexpanded. Note that the `.` is literal; the directory must have a dot in its name. Does it?

Comment: As an aside, it's safer to use an array for this: `temp=("$dest_dir"*)` (assuming that the `.` is a mistake) – now `temp` contains the expanded glob, and blanks / special characters in filenames don't matter.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: The directory is named e.g. "dir_01.4563". There is nothing I can do about it. No, the dot is not a mistake.

Comment: `makes the ls command to fail`, whats the error message?

Comment: Are you sure you're in the right directory, and that the variable doesn't contain any gremlins (like nonprinting characters)?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
TEMP=$(ls ${dest_dir}.*)
```

As others noted though, parsing `ls` output is generally not a good idea..